# Designing the UI of a chrome extension's popup

Tags: website-design, usability, gui-design, web-app, color

I just built a chrome extension for my college. It helps students know their total marks and % 
without manually adding their marks. The user doesn't interact with the popup. He only watches the result displayed.

**Here is how the popup looks when opened (I captured the whole screen):**

[image]

**The closeup of popup when opened is :**

[image]

I've got a few questions on its UI:

1) How should I display the output.Should I put it as

```
 Total : 524/725

 Percentage : 72.2%
```

**or** just

524/725

72.2%

Should I use caps or non-caps for the words(total and percentage) if at all I use them.
And Oh, should I use "%" (symbol) or "percentage"??

2) I have no Idea whatsoever to put over in my popup.
Any suggestions on what to put apart from the main output.Like facebook share, G+, Twitter,
about us, support website, logo etc.

3) What colour do u suggest? for background or text or any other thing?

I might use anything, but I'd love to take advice from experienced folks like you, which would better the User's experience.

*After all an average user might not care about whether I used JSON objects in parameter passing or not, but he'll care about the UI.*

**Edit:**
I've built the extension at that time itself. Dropped here after two years  to make this edit.

It makes use of the third suggestion by @Derek S; except the [X] button, a different font, and minor variations in colour.

You can check out the extension [here](http://goo.gl/MtJzZe).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I would try and do it..

[image: Example 1]

I would also color code the numbers so that if you have a good mark it's green, but if you aren't doing so well then it would be orange like this...

[image: Example 2]

You could just do something in your code like

```
if (PERCENTAGE <= 30) {
makeColorOrange();
}
if (PERCENTAGE > 30 || PERCENTAGE < 50) {
makeColorYellow();
}
else {
makeColorGreen();
}
```

EDIT: I would also add a [X] box in the bottom right of the popup. Make it stay forever on the page until the user presses the [X] button.

Also depending on the importance of your content you may find that the percentages are more important and you could do something like this...

[image]

Comment: Just a note on color: green does not necessarily equal good, nor does any other color equal a certain level/state/mood. I like the color coding, but be sure to pick an appropriate one for your audience.

Comment: @Derek S really loving it. I can't wait to implement it. Thanks a ton buddy! Awesome stuff!!